# How do I force my computer to use a different python version?

Tags: python, installation, pip, cvxpy

I am using an Ubuntu Bash on Windows. I want to write a python program using CVXPY. Unfortunately this is not compatible with Python 2.7.1, what I normaly use. Therefore, I installed python 3.7.10. But somehow I cannot convince my computer to use this python version instead. I actually do not want to deinstall Python 2.7.1, because most of my programs where written with it and I am afraid to cause compatibility errors.

Do you have any advice?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which IDE are you using,If you are using visual studio or pycharm it's pretty easy

Comment: I normally write my programs in Sublime Text and then execute them via the ubuntu bash by the command python anyprogram.py

Comment: I can't help you in that then sorry

Comment: Just us the right binary. In your case probably `python3 my_cvxpy_script.py` works. But you might also look for system-wide python-interpreters with `whereis python` to get a list. Alternatively, and this is the most clean approach: use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments).